How to draw a point cloud inside a instance in open3d python
I try to make my point cloud inside a instance, so that i can have it and an GUI.
But, i am stuck, Curently the button show is face and barelly. i dont know how to handle it.
There is my code:

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance = o3d.visualization.gui.Application.instance
        self.instance.initialize()
        self.vis = self.instance.create_window("Open3D Window", 1024, 768)
        layout = o3d.visualization.gui.Vert(10, o3d.visualization.gui.Margins(10))
        self.file_button = o3d.visualization.gui.Button("File")
        layout.add_child(self.file_button)
        self.vis.add_child(layout)
        self.scene = o3d.visualization.gui.SceneWidget()
        self.scene.scene = o3d.visualization.rendering.Open3DScene(self.vis.renderer)
        self.vis.add_child(self.scene)

    def draw_geometries(self, geometries):
        render = o3d.visualization.rendering.MaterialRecord()
        render.shader = "defaultUnlit"
        
        self.scene.scene.add_geometry("geometry", geometries, render)
        
    def run(self):
        self.instance.run()


(the point cloud is valide and working btw)
i try to setup the caméras, but it crash every time. I try to change the shader but didn't change a thing. i dont know what to do
